# Use a PHP variable in Javascript / Ajax without showing in the inspect element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

i want to send emails with de mandrill api. I have mi apikey in a php var but when i do var `apikey='<?php echo$apikey;?>';` this shows in the inspect elemnt.

its posibble hide, encrypt or something the variable with php, javascript, ajax or json?

this is and example of my code:

```
<?php
$apikey='aaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var apikey='<?php echo$apikey;?>';
   sendEmail();
 function sendEmail() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',
    data: {
      'key': apikey,
      'message': {
        'from_email': 'FROM_EMAIL_GOES_HERE',
        'to': [{
            'email': $('.email').val(), // get email from form
            'name': $('.name').val(), // get name from form
            'type': 'to'
          }
        ],
        'autotext': 'true',
        'subject': 'EMAIL_SUBJECT_GOES_HERE',
        'html': "Hey *|COOLFRIEND|*, we've been friends for *|YEARS|*.", // example of how to use the merge tags
        'track_opens': true,
        'track_clicks': true,
      }
    }
  }).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response); // if you're into that sorta thing
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Not possible.  You can't ask the browser to use a value without telling the browser what that value is.

Comment: Not possible, but what you can do instead is, call a php page requesting it to send email. Which shall in turn call the mandrill API and shall take care of email sending.

`NOTE - Anything you do or put on browser can easily be accessed and will always be visible using any inspector tool`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup a php service and use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to do the transferring work. Then just have AJAX do the front end work and send the subject/body/etc to the php service.

Comment: You should be sending the email from your server code (PHP) not from your webpage

Answer (score 0):

@Lifz works great for me

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```